# Auto-indent in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, indentation, code-formatting

We always write code like this formal:

```
void main(){
  if(){
    if()
    }
```

[image]

But when I use [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B), the display is:

```
void main(){
if(){
if()
}
```

[image]

How do I use Notepad++ to auto indent?

Thanks to [Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/412449/325514), I have set it, but it does not take any effect. The snapshot is below:

[image]

I am using Notepad++ version 5.1.3.

Answer (score 142):

Notepad++ will only auto-insert subsequent indents if you manually indent the first line in a block; otherwise you can re-indent your code after the fact using `TextFX > TextFX Edit > Reindent C++ code`.

Comment: If your version is missing the DLL you can get it from the ZIP 5.9.0 version. Some of the later versions did not include this DLL. http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v5.9.0.html

Comment: I actually found this while looking for a way to format javascript code. Turns out, this works for .js files as well!

Comment: @Fostah: you can also install the "Text FX Character" via >Plugins>Plugin Manager>Show Plugin Manager

Comment: @scronide, Is there a shortcut key for this?

Comment: Note that despite the name, it absolutely also correctly re-indented the javascript code I was trying to fix the indentation of. No reason I would expect it not to, just mentioning, since the name *is* rather specific. Dunno why the author of that library felt he had to give special preference to C++... :D

Comment: It doesn't work with User-Defined Languages, I'm trying to use it with GLSL which is mostly C-like.

Comment: So how does one get started going `TextFX >` ? I've checked all the menus, plugins, and help file and I don't see anything that looks like that.  I can tell Notepadd++ is powerful, but I barely use it because it's so complicated it's almost a no-starter.

Answer (score 108):

If the TextFX menu does not exist, you need to download & install the plugin. **Plugins->Plugin Manager->Show Plugin Manager** and then check the plugin *TextFX Characters*. Click 'install,' restart Notepad++.

In version Notepad++ v6.1.3, I resolve with:
Plugin Manager->Show Plugin Manager** and then check the plugin "Indent By Fold"

Comment: Indent by fold is awesome. The fact that it works in arbitrary formatting (*XML, C/++/#, etc.*) is great. Only problem with it is the "undo" stack. When used, if you wish to undo to a point before when you indented, you have to undo through **every** line re-indentation, as it doesn't get added to the stack as a single command. Basically, be careful when working with *long* files.

Comment: Hi @Dan the undo problem seem to have been fixed in newer version of indent by fold...

Comment: Yes, It doesn't exist and there's no Plugin Manager.

Answer (score 31):

There seems to be an option for auto-format of XML at least. It can be found at `TextFX -> TextFX HTML Tidy -> Tidy: reindent XML`.

Comment: you need TextFx plugin for this

Answer (score 29):

Most developers of text editing programs misuse this name (auto-indent). The correct name is "maintain indentation". Auto-indent is what you actually want, but it is not implemented.

I would also like to see this feature in Notepad++.

Answer (score 22):

In the latest version (at least), you can find it through:

- **Settings** (menu)
- **Preferences...**
- **MISC** (tab)
- lower-left checkbox list
- "**Auto-indent**" is the 2nd option in this group

[**EDIT**] Though, I don't think it's had the best implementation of Auto-indent. So, check to make sure you have version 5.1 -- auto-indent got an overhaul recently, so it auto-corrects your indenting.

---

Do also note that you're missing the block for the 2nd `if`:

```
void main(){
  if(){
    if() { }  # here
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that this auto-indent setting in Notepad++ assumes you do the first indent in a block manually; it doesn't auto-format the code for you.

Comment: I got your meaning just now,please forgive my poor Eng...
My mother language is Chinese...

Answer (score 16):

You can use 'Indent by fold' plugin. Install it from the plugin manager. It works fine for me.

Comment: Indent by fold is great, except that it only indents by fold ;) In situations where you've indented a list initialization, unless the language uses a folding character to delimit the initializer, it'll end up un-indenting. An example is a multi-line array initialization in PHP using `array( ... )`, where `()` are non-folding.

Answer (score 7):

For those who using version 7.8.5, the Auto-indent settings is now located at "Settings" -> "Preferences..." -> "Auto-Completion".

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In the 6.6.8 version I installed the NppAutoIndent plugin from Plugins > Plugin Manager > Show Plugin Manager.
Then I selected the Smart Indent option in Plugin > NppAutoIndent. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

For those who use Notepad++ v6.8.1 and later, the auto-indent setting now is placed in menu *Settings* → *Preferences* → *MISC.* → *Auto Indent*.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A little update: You can skip the TextFX Plugin and just use **Tidy2**. Here you can configure your own formating-rules for different types of codes. Easy to install and remove within

**Notepad++ > Plugins > Plugin Manager > Show Plugin Manager**

and just search for **Tidy2** and install it. Done.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: More information about configuration can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865770/using-tydy2-for-notepad

Comment: its quite difficult to use this compare to other plugins

Answer (score 3):

You can add "Text FX Character" plugin. Download it from https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/TextFX/ and  install it via

```
Plugins → Plugin Manager → Show Plugin Manager.
```

Then you will find a new "TextFX" menu:

```
Menu TextFX → TextFX Edit → Reindent C++ code
```

[image]

**To add shortcut for Indentation**.

Click on *Settings* → *Shortcut Mapper...* set the shortcut key you prefer. I prefer <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: This plugin is no longer available

Answer (score 2):

Try the [UniversalIndentGUI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/universalindent/files/uigui/UniversalIndentGUI_1.0.2/UniversalIndentGUI_1.0.2_NotepadPPplugin.zip/download) plugin for Notepad++. It re-indents code based on some parameters. It worked well for me.

Comment: Note that the link is direct to the download.  The website is: http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/.  Also, this appears to be a GUI for configuring a reformating tool, rather than automatically formatting the text correctly to start with.

Answer (score 2):

This may seem silly, but in the original question, Turion was editing a plain text file. Make sure you choose the correct language from the Language menu

Answer (score 0):

Install Tidy2 plugin. I have Notepad++ v6.2.2, and Tidy2 works fine so far.

Answer (score 0):

First download plugin manager [this link](https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager/releases) then unzip the zip folder and copy this inside your program/ notepad++ folder . then restart your notepad++. then you see  plugin manager inside plugin menu . then click plugin manager then click show plugin manager . It shows all your plugin list . from the list in bottom find XML tools , checked it and install it. then restart your notepad++. After open a document then  plugins/xml tools/pretty plain(indent text) then enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

`Tab` and `Shift+Tab` are actually mapped to Edit => Indent => Increase Line Indent / Decrease Line Indent.

Answer (score -1):

Try to save the file before, then it will indent.

Comment: It could be comment!

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a little more?