# Selecting a one picture from multiple images and dragging it on screen on Java Applet

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, applet, awt

I am just able to select  one images from multiple images and dragging of images is not possible on entire screen,Below are the three images displayed Java Applet ,I wanted to select it and then drag it anywhere on the  Applet Frame

```
     import java.applet.*;
     import java.awt.*;
     import java.awt.event.*;

      /*
     <applet code="SelectingImage" width=500 height=300>
     <param name=img1 value=arrow1.jpg>
     <param name=img2 value=Home.jpg> 
     <param name=img3 value=arrow2.jpg>
     </applet>
      */
   public class SelectingImage extends Applet implements                   
    MouseListener,MouseMotionListener{                     
Image img[]=new Image[3];
int y=10;
int a;
int dx,dy;
int xpos,ypos;
int x[]=new int[3];
boolean imgdrag,imgclick,enabled=true;
public void init(){
try{
    MediaTracker mt=new MediaTracker(this);
    img[0]=getImage(getDocumentBase(),getParameter("img1"));
    img[1]=getImage(getDocumentBase(),getParameter("img2"));
    img[2]=getImage(getDocumentBase(),getParameter("img3"));
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        x[i]=(i+1)*150;
        mt.addImage(img[i],i);
    }
    mt.waitForAll();
    addMouseListener(this);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) { };
}


public void paint(Graphics g){
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            g.drawImage(img[i],x[i],y,null);
            }
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            if(xpos>=x[i] && xpos<=img[i].getWidth(null)+x[i] &&     
                        ypos>=10 && ypos<=img[i].getHeight(null))
                             {                                                                                                
                   g.drawRect(x[i],10,img[i].getWidth(null),img[i].getHeight(null));                                                                 

                a=i;
                imgclick=true;
                break;
            }
            else{
                imgclick=false;
            }
        }
        if(imgclick){
            g.drawImage(img[a],xpos,ypos,null);
        }
}
               public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent me) 
               {
            xpos=me.getX(); 
                ypos=me.getY(); 
            showStatus("Mouse at"+me.getX());
            repaint();
                }
               public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent me) {
                } 
               public void mousePressed (MouseEvent me) {} 
               public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent me) {}  
               public void mouseExited (MouseEvent me) {} 
               public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me){
        xpos=me.getX();
        ypos=me.getY();

    showStatus("Mouse at"+me.getX());
    repaint();
              }
         public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me){
           xpos=me.getX();
    ypos=me.getY();
    repaint();
          }

          }
```

sorry for wrong indentation of code since iam newbie

Comment: The applet can't do anything outside of it's frame.

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See this answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.  If you need to support older AWT based APIs, see [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

Comment: See [Auto-Indent in Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/412427/418556) & [Adding Code Formatting Tools in Notepad++](http://www.blogetcetera.com/2012/adding-code-formatting-tools-notepad/).  I don't use Notepad++ but that is what I stumbled across on a quick search based on "Notepad++ format code".  Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow!

Comment: See also the advice of @JamesBlack re the applet security sand-box.  By default, an applet would *not* be able to D-n-D outside its own applet context.  Yet another reason to achieve this in a standard desktop app. first.

Comment: i donot want applet to D-n-D out side its frame but instead i wanted to D-n-D inside Applet frame,Please run the code you will understand the problem

Comment: You may want to look at https://eyeasme.com/Shayne/JAVA_DND_EXAMPLE/ as you are missing the DnD parts.

Comment: even though i have jdk1.7.0, i unable to run that applet on browser and my none of the applet are running on browser please help