# Notepad++ doesn't correctly indent close brace

Tags: notepad++

When I open a block of code in Notepad++ with a `{`, it correctly adds a `}` but doesn't indent it properly.

Expected:

```
if(p){
    ....
}
```

Actual:

```
if(p){
    ....
    }
```

I can't find an option to change the

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto-indent in Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412427/auto-indent-in-notepad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unchecking `TextFX->TextFX Settings -> Autoclose ([{ Brace` fixed this for me.