# Copying char * pointer to char array variable

Tags: c++

I've created a Word scribble solver and it basically computes the permutations of a given word and compares it with the available dictionary.
But the problem is I've to copy a char pointer into an array char variable to compare them and I don't know how to do it.
Below is my code snippet:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<ctype>

using namespace std;

void swap(char *x, char *y)
{
    char temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

void permute(char *a, int l, int r)
{
    char word[25], word1[25];
    fstream flame;
    if(l == r)
    {
        word1 = *a;      /* <— Error! */
        flame.open("dic.sly", ios::in);
        while(!flame.eof())
        {
            flame << word;
            tolower(word[0]);
            if(strcmp(word, word1) == 0)
                cout << word;
        }
        flame.close();
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = l; i <= r; i++)
        {
            swap((a + l), (a + i));
            permute(a, l + 1, r);
            swap((a + l), (a + i));
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
    char str[] = "lonea";
    int n = strlen(str);
    permute(str, 0, n - 1);
}
```

I've quoted where I'm getting the error.
Please, correct if there are any mistakes.

Comment: Plz Indent  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46848194/1465553

Comment: It would be greatly appreciated if you would fix your indentation to make your code easier to read. Some examples of good indentation can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Styles

Comment: `#include<string>` -- This is not the correct header for the C-style strings.  The correct header is `<cstring>`.  The `<string>` header is for `std::string`, which you make no use of in your program whatsoever.

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy one C-style string to another you have to use `strcpy(word1, a);`. Only if you use `std::string` (recommended!) can you assign using `=`.

You also have a mistake in `flame<<word;` where you try to write to the input file. To read words you need `flame >> word;`.

It probably would have been easier to use `std::swap` instead of implementing your own.

Another bit is `tolower(word[0]);` which doesn't modify the parameter but returns the result. You ought to save that.

Comment: This code was written for turbo c++ compiler(academic reason), sorry for incorrect header files